# How do I concatenate an element of a string array to a string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char a[7]= "car";
char b[7]="yyoug";
strcat(a,b[2]);
puts(a);
  return 0;
}
```

This won't compile. It says "passing argument 2 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast." I haven't been taught the use of pointers.

Comment: `b[2]` gives the values of the 3rd element in the array. `&b[2]` gives the address.. That is expected from `strcat()`

Comment: What's the expected output you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! but now it will add "oug" to the word "car." All I want is the letter 'o'

Comment: Use `strcat(a,&b[2]);` or `strcat(a,b+2);`

Comment: @Jeremy I'm looking for 'caro'

Comment: If you just want to append one character, you can use `strncat(a,&b[2],1);`

Comment: `a[3] = b[2]` if you just want to append the one character

Answer (score 3):

`b[2]` is of `char` type but `strcat` expects its both arguments are of `char *` type.
Use `strncat` instead. It will append only one byte, i.e. `b[2]` to the first string if the third argument passed is `1`

```
strncat(a, &b[2], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use `strncat` because you want to learn how it works, then @hacks example is completly perfect. But if you just want to concat on character to `a` you can also use

`a[3] = b[2];`

But please keep in mind, either solution only works, if the the destination array, in your case `a` is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without using malloc this might help explain what's going in

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  //positions  0    1    2    3
  //"car" == ['c', 'a', 'r', '\0']
  char a[7] = "car";
  char b[7] = "yyoug";

  //strlen("car") == 3;
  //"car"[3]      == ['\0']; 

  a[strlen(a)]    = b[2]; 
  assert(a[3] == 'o');

  a[strlen(a) + 1] = '\0';
  assert(a[4] == '\0');
  puts(a); 
    return 0;
}
```